# Chrome bug? Cannot capitalise label following file input

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Using the following code, I am unable to capitalise a label that directly follows a file input field in chrome:

#### CSS

```
label {
    text-transform: capitalize;    
}
```

#### HTML

```
<label for="book-file">file</label>
<input type="file" name="a_file" id="a_file"><label for="a_file">required</label>
```

Error reproduced:

**JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Nc27q/**

A way to resolve this is to move the second label onto its own line (**see: http://jsfiddle.net/Nc27q/1/** ) within the HTML or even placing a space in between the HTML tags.

The second label is added using Javascript (as an error message) which is why it is not placed on another line.

Does anybody know why chrome does this and how I can get around it in a CSS only way?

Comment: Recommend reporting the bug if you haven't (or someone else hasn't) already: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed look like a bug. It's like it's seeing the file input in front of the text and treating that as part of the word, so not seeing the "r" in "required" as the first character in need of capitalization.

Adding

```
label:before {
    content: " ";
}
```

to force the space seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Nc27q/4/ Since this is a Chrome-specific issue, you don't have to worry about pseudo-elements not being supported... (Of course, you may want to target it a bit more tightly than I have above.)

Comment: Thanks - this does indeed fix it. It is fairly odd behavour by Chrome - but I guess it is through the way it creates its "No file chosen" message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is caused by the way Chrome detects what to capitalize and what not. You don't have any spaces in your code, so it simply says `file<input>required`. Chrome's logic would probably determine that this is one word (or sentence), causing it to intentionally ignore it.

You might be able to use `label:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }` instead.

Answer (score -1):

text-transform property doesn't have capitalize as one of its keyword values; you want uppercase. it works, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/Nc27q/2/

Comment: *"text-transform property doesn't have capitalize as one of its keyword values"* Yes, it does: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-transform

Comment: doh. my bad. idk why i thought that.